# TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, urllib2, export-to-csv

Python 2.7

Am trying to get the company names on this page and save them in a csv file.

The first part of my code works fine but there's space between each returned object (company name).

I also had trouble writing the result and save it in a csv file, which made me believe it's because of the space in between makes 'data' not iterable.

Can someone help fix the syntax? Many thanks!

My code (first part)

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://app.core-apps.com/weftec2014/exhibitors/list/A')
page = response.read()
page = page[4632:] 


def get_next_target(page): 
    start_link = page.find("<a href='/weftec2014/exhibitors/")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    else:
        start_place = start_link+73 #to get company names after the first <div>
        end_place = page.find("</div>", start_place)
        item = page[start_place:end_place]
        return item, end_place

def print_all_com(page): #return company names
    while True:
        item, end_place = get_next_target(page)
        if item:
            print item
            page = page[end_place:]
        else:
            break


data = print_all_com(page)
```

second part (CSV writer)

```
import csv
with open('weftec_list.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yumiyang/Documents/MCComponenet_crawler.py", line 32, in <module>
    writer.writerows(data)
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable
```

Comment: there's no return statement in `print_all_com`, so `data` is probably `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but probably it should be:

```
def print_all_com(page): #return company names

    results = []

    while True:
        item, end_place = get_next_target(page)
        if item:
            results.append( [ item.strip() ] )
            #print item
            page = page[end_place:]
        else:
            break

    return results
```